# running a windows program from ssh cygwin

Tags: cygwin, execution

I'm running a setup installer windows executable made using Inno setup through ssh with cygwin. It does not error out. I tried echoing $? and %errorlevel%; $? is undefined and %errorlevel% is zero.
There is no output either.

```
setup.exe /silent /loadinf="file.inf"
```

It does nothing.
Also, when I put the command in a batch file and ran it. Again, nothing happens. I did notice that it pauses briefly.
What do you folks suggest as ways of investigating this?

I'm thinking of using other executables and then if they work, I package them similarly and try that.
Also, I should try using X-windows packages on cygwin.

Comment: Another way to try and start processes with cygwin is using "cygstart". You should specify the circumstances in which your executable does work, though.